# problem retrieving list of products in InApp purchase in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I am using below code to retrieve list of products

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are disabled");

        //Request products.Retrieving list of products
        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.test.SinFinder"]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
    }
}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    NSLog(@"count : %d",count);
    if (count > 0) {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    } else if (!validProduct) {
        NSLog(@"No products available");
    }    
}
```

In handling response I am getting count zero and so in `updatedTransactions` methods it goes to `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` and logs error.
I have no idea what is going wrong or what is missing
**Or Is this necessary i.e. list of products as I just need to lock a feature once app is purchased**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to print the products on gdb and if you find the products as invalid ,[refer this link in that case.](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)

[refer this for a complete look of developing in app into our application](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

TNQ

Comment: if i am only need to unlock a feature on purchase, do i need to get list of products?

Comment: can u explain your requirement in detail?

Comment: Thanks Dinakar, this link is the bomb!  http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Comment: @NathanPrather Glad that my pointer landed you to a blog which helped you.You are welcome...